# Round timestamp in cronjob

Tags: python, cron

I have 4 cronjobs running every minut.
The first script begin when the cronjob is initiated.
The second has a sleep for 15 seconds.
The third has a sleep for 30 seconds.
The fourth has a sleep for 45 seconds.

This is my way of having a job running every 15 second.

It works, but if anyone has a better way, please let me know.

Me actual challenge is that I begin every script with saving a timestamp which I use for other purposes and with other values in a database.
It shows every cronjob various with +/- some seconds.

Is it possible to round the timestamp to nearest whole minut, plus 15 seconds, plus 30 seconds and plus 45 seconds:

```
timestamp = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

So if my cronjobs begins at 12:00:01 or 11:59:58 all 4 scripts will have the timestamps:

```
12:00:00
12:00:15
12:00:30
12:00:45
```

I hope it makes sense and it's possible?

Comment: Rounding to the nearest 15 seconds is easy.  What have you tried and how did it fail?  The bigger picture of your problem seems rather problematic to me, though.  Why are you doing things this way, and what task does these cron jobs perform?  It seems that there is probably a better way to achieve that goal.

Comment: I'm able to call a stock API for quotes/values, and the API takes a timestamp. I would like to query for "clean" timestamp every 15 second.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the time into hours mins and secs, and round them up to the nearest min and hour.

```
 def split_hour(timer):
     hour=timer[,2]
     return hour
 def split_min(timer):
     min=timer[3,6]
     return min
 def split_sec(timer,min):
     sec=timer[6,]
     if sec>=30:
          sec=0
          min=min+1
          return min
     else:
          sec=0
```

you could do something like this I might of got the symbols wrong, but you could split the sec and round it up or down then add it to the mins.

Comment: That won't get me the "clean" seconds I think?

Comment: This seems like an answer to a somewhat unrelated question.

Comment: What I tried to do is to spilt the time so that he could round up the secs if you change "if sec>=30:" to if sec>=55: you could round up the last 5 sec

Answer (score 0):

This function will round to the nearest minute, i.e. if seconds in the timestamp is less than 30 to the previous whole minute, if 30 or more to the next whole minute.

```
import datetime


def round_seconds(timestamp):
    ts_sec = timestamp.timetuple()[5]
    timestamp_rounded = timestamp.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    if ts_sec < 30:
        return timestamp_rounded
    else:
        return timestamp_rounded + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Now you can get your timestamp like this:

```
timestamp = round_seconds(datetime.datetime.now())
```